# Close (red 'x') on GUI Text editor not exiting

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to learn to build basic GUI's, I have started with a simple text editor. I have been able to get through things so far pretty well, but I am running into a strange issue. When I was going through building it I was able to click the red "X" exit button (top right) of the window and change a few things and restart it. But after defining some functions it seems to have stopped working, the editor launches fine and works with the menu pieces I have used so far but its not letting me "X" out. I have to restart the kernel to get it to close and thats getting annoying. I tried looking through it but I didnt change anything that I know of that should cause this. So I figured I would bring it to the experts and get opinions/experience.

```
#!/user/bin/env python
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 300))
        self.control=wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        filemenu=wx.Menu()

        About_Menu=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, '&About','Info about')

        Exit_Menu=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,'E&xit','Term')

        Open_Menu=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,'&Open','Open File')

        menuBar=wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,'&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, About_Menu)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, Exit_Menu)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, Open_Menu)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog( self, 'The Editor', 'About the Editor', wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog( self, 'Test Exit','Exit',  wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        self.dirname=''
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self, 'Choose a file', self.dirname, '','*.*', wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            f=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

app=wx.App(False)
frame=MainWindow(None, 'Sample')
app.MainLoop
```

[image: This is what i have to restart to get it closed]

Comment: I am using "Canopy" as my dev environment, it has its own kernel that runs .py for me. I have been using it through school but i am done with my work for the week so i started looking at other things to learn. As for my machine, I am at work (IBM Mainframe Operator) and its working great. They have my paths set very funny here with each of us using a virtual inside of a machine so i dont know whats up I just copied the path that way.

Comment: Ill add a picture of it.

Comment: OK, I guess I don't know what Enthought means with its terminology; I'll delete my comments. (I still don't believe you really have a `/user/bin/env`, but whatever; that's not relevant to this problem.)

Comment: Talked to our LAN support guy and he said that they setup a specific path for it so it didnt use the one our Python compilers use.... IDK